# Python trying to download a file with login and password

Tags: python

I am trying to Access a comfort panel with windows CE from Windows 10 and get a audittrail.cvs with python. After logging in using a username and password, I try to download the csv file with the audit trail info but the csv containing the HTML info gets downloaded instead. How do I download the actual file?

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

loginurl = ("http://10.70.148.11/FormLogin")
secure_url = ("http://10.70.148.11/StorageCardSD?UP=TRUE&FORCEBROWSE")
downloadurl = ("http://10.70.148.11/StorageCardSD/AuditTrail0.csv?UP=TRUE&FORCEBROWSE")
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
    'Login': 'Admin',
    'Password': 'Pass'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    r = s.get(secure_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
    
req = requests.get(downloadurl, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('audittrail.csv', 'wb')

csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: You're not using your logged-in session for downloading.

Comment: how do I use the logged in session?

Comment: You did `with requests.session() as s` and discarded this session right after login. Then you use a standalone `requests.get` to download the file. What's going on here?

Comment: with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    req = s.get(downloadurl, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    url_content = req.content
    csv_file = open('audittrail9.csv', 'wb')
    csv_file.write(url_content)
    csv_file.close()

Comment: still gets me same csv info

Comment: Please [edit] your question to incorporate any additional information or code. Comments are not for extended code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to get the file, you are no longer in the requests session and therefore do not have the necessary cookies.
Try making the requests with your session logged in (the requests session).
It should work.